# Configuration file contains invalid cp1252 characters in pip.exe

Tags: python, pip, windows-10

I am facing this error while installing any Python library on Windows 10(Python 3.11.4).

Tried the following solutions,

- Re-installed python
- Tried with 3 different versions of Python
- Installed pip separately using get-pip.py file available on different internet resources, but still no use.
- Changed the encoding of pip.exe to UTF-8

This question may look similar to a few of the earlier questions on this forum, but unfortunately, none of them is exactly the same or the answers to those questions did not help me fix this issue.

Comment: I tried installing the Older/Stable version of Python(3.10.0) with custom options and it is working fine. It's weird that the same process doesn't work for the latest version of Python(> 3.10.0).